# Are the "average visit duration" and "engagement" metrics accurate on mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, flurry

We are using the mobile SDK for Google Analytics on our iOS and Android apps. Every call to our API server is accompanied with a GA call with the appropriate labels.

So far the analytics data looks fine, however we are seeing the following abnormalities in data:

The "average visit duration" is 30 minutes. Which seems quite long for a mobile app.
Under Engagement, 12% of visits and 22.56% of pageviews are for 1800+ seconds. Again, this seems abnormally long.
Is there anything we could be doing wrong with the GA calls that would affect this? I can confirm that we are only making calls when the user interacts with the app directly (and you can't make background calls in iOS anyway). Or is this a known problem with GA? We are meeting several investors soon and need to be able to pull accurate analytics data.

Comment: kinda more of a "web masters" topic. However "30minutes" seems like a golden donkey.

Answer (score -1):

On Flurry, the session length is defined simply as the length of time between the start application event and the end application event which can vary by platform. There are some circumstances, including application crashes, where no end time can be recorded and hence the session length is unknown. Those instances are not included in the average and median session length calculation. The length of the session can vary based on how you integrate the SDK into your application if you do not follow the recommended practices. (Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)